# Why do you warm a Dutch oven up before baking bread?

Tags: baking, equipment, bread

I want to attempt to make bread in my Dutch oven. Most of the recipes that I have found say to warm your Dutch oven up before putting the dough in. I have found a few recipes that say you don't have to warm it up first. Why should you warm it up first, and will it make a big difference in the bread? And what breads are best for baking in a Dutch oven?

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/43537/45428

Comment: I'd say the "why warm it up" part of this question seems like a duplicate of that previous question, though the conclusion there is far from solid. The "what breads are best" isn't a duplicate, though.

Answer (score 5):

The point is you are actually using the dutch oven as the oven itself here--so you warm the dutch oven for the same reason that you would pre-heat your conventional oven: you want the bread to immediately go into the hot oven, instead of slowly raising the temperature.

With a hot dutch oven, you get the "oven spring" that you would get from putting the loaf into a hot oven, and the dutch oven traps the steam that the bread gives off, so it helps keep the crust soft while the bread expands.  This is a great way to bake bread at home in ovens that don't have steam injection.

Comment: You might find the linked question interesting. The assertion from one of the testers at America's Test Kitchen is that this isn't really a big deal.

Comment: That makes since I never thought of it being like an oven. I read a lot of America's Test Kitchen articles I will check that out.

Comment: @Catija, I did find that interesting, but not convincing; indeed, the test done by the OP in that question suggests that pre-heating does still help